# How to install Node 14 on a M2 Chip Apple Macbook Air?

Tags: node.js, nvm, apple-silicon

I need to work on a project that uses Node v14.17.3. In my previous Macbook with intel chip I had node 16 but in this particular project I ran `npm install node@14.17.3` and everything worked fine.

The project has the version specified on package.json file:

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "v14.17.3"
  },
```

When I try to install node 14 on the project using my M2 Chip Macbook I get the following error:

```
 command sh -c node installArchSpecificPackage
npm ERR! npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for node-darwin-arm64@14.17.3.
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     /Users/enzo/.npm/_logs/2023-02-04T02_37_49_054Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'node-bin-darwin-arm64/package.json'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - /Users/enzo/Documents/Project/frontend/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js
npm ERR!     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/enzo/Documents/TeCambio/frontend/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:19:27)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: [
npm ERR!     '/Users/enzo/Documents/Project/frontend/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js'
npm ERR!   ]
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Node.js v18.14.0
```

Is there any solution/workaround for this issue? I was thinking about installing Rosseta and NVM but I'd rather do this with some better solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: node 16 was the first release with official darwin-arm64 binaries

Answer (score 8):

The approved answer didn't work for me. I had to switch the `arch` to `x86`

```bash
arch -x86_64 zsh
nvm install 14
nvm us 14
```

That works for me.

Comment: It won't worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to exit back to arm64 after this.

Answer (score 4):

**For M2 chip**

> To clarify, when installing Node.js, it attempts to download the darwin arm64 version, which is only available from Node.js 16 onwards. If you're using an **M1/M2 Mac**, you'll need to use a **Rosetta** shell to install Node.js versions earlier than 16.

Here's how you can launch the Terminal using **Rosetta**:

1. Navigate to the Applications folder in Finder.
2. Use the Search icon to find and type "Terminal."
3. Right-click on the Terminal icon that appears and choose "Get Info."
4. In the Get Info window, tick the box labeled "Open using Rosetta."
5. Close any currently open Terminal windows and exit the application. Then, reopen the Terminal.
6. After following these steps, you should be able to install Node versions earlier than 16 using NVM, and the installation should be successful.

After reopening the terminal(Rosetta), this command should work.

```
nvm install 14.21.3
```

[image: Get Info option]

[image: Open using Rosetta]

For more info: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2944

Answer (score 2):

I used brew and restarted my terminal after

```
brew install node@14

node -v
```

Comment: :(  node@14 (disabled) - https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node@14

Answer (score -1):

I could make it work:

For Apple Computers with M1 and M2 Chip you'll have to use nvm.

1. Install nvm
2. Install node version 14.17.3
3. Create .nvmrc folder at root level of the project you're working on
4. Run `nvm use`
5. Run `npm install` to install your project dependencies

And that's it... you can use any Node version on your M1 or M2 Macs.

PD: I think you need to have Rosetta installed in order to install NVM on new macs. You can install it simply by running:

```
usr/sbin/softwareupdate –install-rosetta –agree-to-license
```

Hope it helps!!!